# Where is the 'NilClass' singleton instance instantiated?

Tags: ruby

I would like to know where the `nil` singleton object is instantiated in the Ruby source code.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take a look at the Ruby source code on Github, we can see that most of the kernel functionality is initialized in [`InitVM_Object`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/38e05ff3e194268fd2f38ac7c9530298e464f07b/object.c). However, `nil` is conspicuously absent, and the only clue of its existence is

```
/*
 * An obsolete alias of +nil+
 */
rb_define_global_const("NIL", Qnil);
```

which, admittedly, I didn't actually know that `NIL` even worked in Ruby, but that's beside the point. Now we know that, in Ruby's C code, `Qnil` is our "nil" object. As it turns out, we can trace that back to *its* origin, in [`ruby.h`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/bcf8ce8494a6afb79196b37e856a556a649d0794/include/ruby/ruby.h). `Qnil` is not a variable; it's a `#define` pragma.

```
#define Qnil RUBY_Qnil
```

`RUBY_Qnil`, on the other hand, is defined as an enum constant.

```
enum ruby_special_consts {
    RUBY_Qfalse = 0x00,     /* ...0000 0000 */
    RUBY_Qtrue  = 0x14,     /* ...0001 0100 */
    RUBY_Qnil = 0x08,       /* ...0000 1000 */
    ...
}
```

So it looks like `nil` is just a happy lie in Ruby. It's not even a real object at all; it's just a special magic number. `true` and `false` are also defined in that same enum. In fact, we can check that this is accurate in Ruby itself.

```
irb(main):009:0> false.object_id
=> 0
irb(main):010:0> true.object_id
=> 20
irb(main):011:0> nil.object_id
=> 8
```

`false`, `true`, and `nil` all have identifiers equal* to the values we found in the enum, so this looks like it.

It's worth noting that while *nil* itself is a happy lie in the VM, the methods on `nil` are, of course, very real. The `NilClass` is defined in [`InitVM_Object`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/38e05ff3e194268fd2f38ac7c9530298e464f07b/object.c), and so are its methods. But `nil` is never *initialized*, per se.

* It's technically possible that your values are different. The enum values listed here are protected by a `#if USE_FLONUM` block, which is set or unset depending on the size of various constants on your system. You can check out the criteria for that flag, as well as several other similar ones, in [`ruby.h`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/bcf8ce8494a6afb79196b37e856a556a649d0794/include/ruby/ruby.h).

Comment: Thank you for your time. I figured out that `nil` is actually nothing more than a value to express the "not an object" notion (via the `Qnil` macro). When it comes to receiver and message sending (the `rb_call*` methods in vm_eval.c) then the `rb_cNilClass` is in charge of sending the messages. feel free to have a look to the `CLASS_OF()` macro to figure it out. So there is no "instantiation" of the `nil` object.

Answer (score 3):

In MRI at least, nil (as well as true and false) are special constants statically created in the "C" interpreter code.

As such they are not created in the normal sense. Instead, its object id is a sort of marker for nil that is tested in the code as needed. While a bit chaotic, this would speed things up quite a bit.

```
/* special constants - i.e. non-zero and non-fixnum constants */
405 enum ruby_special_consts {
406 #if USE_FLONUM
407     RUBY_Qfalse = 0x00,         /* ...0000 0000 */
408     RUBY_Qtrue  = 0x14,         /* ...0001 0100 */
409     RUBY_Qnil   = 0x08,         /* ...0000 1000 */
410     RUBY_Qundef = 0x34,         /* ...0011 0100 */
411 
412     RUBY_IMMEDIATE_MASK = 0x07,
413     RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG    = 0x01, /* ...xxxx xxx1 */
414     RUBY_FLONUM_MASK    = 0x03,
415     RUBY_FLONUM_FLAG    = 0x02, /* ...xxxx xx10 */
416     RUBY_SYMBOL_FLAG    = 0x0c, /* ...0000 1100 */
417 #else
418     RUBY_Qfalse = 0,            /* ...0000 0000 */
419     RUBY_Qtrue  = 2,            /* ...0000 0010 */
420     RUBY_Qnil   = 4,            /* ...0000 0100 */
421     RUBY_Qundef = 6,            /* ...0000 0110 */
422 
423     RUBY_IMMEDIATE_MASK = 0x03,
424     RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG    = 0x01, /* ...xxxx xxx1 */
425     RUBY_FLONUM_MASK    = 0x00, /* any values ANDed with FLONUM_MASK cannot be FLONUM_FLAG */
426     RUBY_FLONUM_FLAG    = 0x02,
427     RUBY_SYMBOL_FLAG    = 0x0e, /* ...0000 1110 */
428 #endif
429     RUBY_SPECIAL_SHIFT  = 8
430 };
```

Answer (score 1):

[It's defined here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5aa52587e86b9e2b03cad8b78307e53b777f1df2/include/ruby/ruby.h#L410-L443).

Namely, we have the lines:

```
RUBY_Qnil   = 0x08

#define RUBY_Qnil   ((VALUE)RUBY_Qnil)
#define Qnil  RUBY_Qnil
```

This is why `nil.object_id == 8`.

`NilClass`, and its methods, are then defined [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/38e05ff3e194268fd2f38ac7c9530298e464f07b/object.c#L4110-L4124):

```
rb_cNilClass = rb_define_class("NilClass", rb_cObject);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "to_i", nil_to_i, 0);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "to_f", nil_to_f, 0);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "to_s", nil_to_s, 0);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "to_a", nil_to_a, 0);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "to_h", nil_to_h, 0);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "inspect", nil_inspect, 0);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "&", false_and, 1);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "|", false_or, 1);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "^", false_xor, 1);
rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "===", rb_equal, 1);

rb_define_method(rb_cNilClass, "nil?", rb_true, 0);
rb_undef_alloc_func(rb_cNilClass);
rb_undef_method(CLASS_OF(rb_cNilClass), "new");
```

Throughout the MRI source code, you'll then find countless references to `Qnil`

Comment: It'd be interesting to contrast this to Rubinius where the C layer is a lot leaner.

Comment: The implementation in Rubinius is [very straightforward](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/4628ce3730626df435089e6c705dc07ead7e32ab/core/nil.rb).

Comment: Doesn't get much simpler than that!

Comment: @TomLord: Actually, that doesn't show where `nil` is instantiated. In fact, if you look at the last line, `nil` is simply assumed to exist. My guess would be that `nil` is defined as part of the `machine`, i.e. in C++, not Ruby.

Comment: @TomLord: Rubinius calls the minimal base object structure that is needed to run the bootstrap Ruby code the *ontology*, and `nil` is defined in the file [`machine/ontology.cpp`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/machine/ontology.cpp#L216).